# Determine the interior, boundary, exterior and closure of the set $S= \{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\mid \forall x_i\in \mathbb Q\}$

Tags: general-topology

Determine the interior, boundary, exterior and closure of the set $$S= \{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\mid  \forall  x_i\in \mathbb Q\}$$
I´m using the following definitions:

- A set is closed if it is the complement of an open set.
- $O$ is open if every point of $O$ has a neighborhood contained in $O$.
- $\operatorname{int}(S)$ is the set of all interior points of $S$. An interior point $x$ of $S$ is such that $x$ has a neighborhood that is contained in $S$.
- $\operatorname{Boundary}(S)$ is the set of all boundary points of $S$. A boundary point $x$ of $S$ is such that every neighborhood of $x$ is both in $S$ and its complement.
- The closure of a set is the intersection of all the closed sets that contain it

I've reached the conclusion that $Int{S}$ is empty and that $Boundary{S}=S$. Is this right?

I'm also having trouble determining $Ext{S}$ and its closure. What do you suggest? I'd like to prove my answers with the definitions given above.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, this might be of use to you.

Comment: Your conclusions are correct. The exterior is also empty.